# held a dubious distinction

Tags: phrase-usage

Does "distinction" mean "the quality of being excellent"?

> NOAA, one of the country’s premier climate-focused agencies, **held a dubious distinction** under former President Donald Trump: It went his entire term without an administrator who had been confirmed by the U.S. Senate. Yesterday, Biden moved to end its string of acting leaders, nominating Rick Spinrad, an oceanographer at Oregon State University (OSU), Corvallis, and a longtime NOAA hand, as the agency’s next head.

> Source:  [Science](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/04/biden-fills-out-science-team-noaa-doe-and-diplomacy-picks)

Comment: a distinction is a difference or something that is noteworthy.

Comment: That was the first definition I checked out. The question is: in the OP, is it a difference between what and what?

Comment: a dubious distinction is being recognized for something that is not good, not great. Ergo, it is a sarcastic way to say: recognized for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A distinction is a difference or something that is noteworthy.  NOAA was distinct because it didn't have an approved Head for the last four-and-a-half years.

A dubious distinction is being recognized for something that is not good, not great. Ergo, it is a sarcastic way to say: recognized for the wrong reasons.